# javascript geocoding from address to latitude,longitude

Tags: wordpress, api, google-maps

I m using google maps api v3. This is my code

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  
   v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);



//var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.52043030000, 73.85674369999);

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 15,
//center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById('searchTextField').value;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode( { 'searchTextField': address}, function(results, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
 var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
 var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
 alert(latitude);
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
  });
  } else {
  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
   }
  });
 }
 </script>
```

I m doing all this in wordpress template file. I m displaying suggestion using autocmplete places. I want that when user select one of the location from suggestion list, map should navigate to that place. It's not going into the if condition i.e. if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

This is html code

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="textbox">
  <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
```

Comment: So you are getting the alert with "Geocode was not successful..."? If not.. you got an error somewhere, if yes.. what was the address you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this code you will see you have an error that says:

```
InvalidValueError: unknown property searchTextField
```

Geocoder accepts 'address' as a property among others, but no 'searchTextField'.
So just change:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'searchTextField': address}, function(results, status) {
```

to:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
```